# Website header looks different on phone than on PC

Tags: android, ios, asp.net

I already tried this, which I found on a few sites:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The problem is my website header is scrunched to half its width on a phone, but on a PC it looks fine.

The site in question is [SamanthaFishFans.com](http://www.samanthafishfans.com)

Can anyone offer a reason why *only the header* (which is part of a Master page) would look wrong on a phone, but the rest of the site would look correct?

The code for the header looks like this:

```
<header>
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <table>
           <tr style="height:82px">
              <td><img src="/Images/SamLogo4.gif" style="height:80px; width:auto" /></td>
              <td style="width:30px"></td>
              <td><h1><b style="vertical-align:bottom;padding-top:20px">KCFishFans.com</b></h1></td>
           </tr>
        </table>

        <div class="clear hideSkiplink" id="MainMenu">
            <a href="#NavigationMenu_SkipLink" style="position:absolute;left:-10000px;top:auto;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;">Skip Navigation Links</a>
            <div class="menu" id="NavigationMenu">
                <ul class="level1">
                    <li><a class="level1" href="Default.aspx">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a class="level1" href="Biography.aspx">Biography</a></li>
                    <li><a class="level1" href="Tourography.aspx">Tourography</a></li>
                    <li><a class="level1" href="Discography.aspx">Discography</a></li>
                    <li><a class="level1" href="Stats.aspx">Statistics</a></li>
                    <li><a class="level1" href="http://KCFishFans.freeforums.net">Messageboard</a></li>
                    <li><a class="level1" href="Help.aspx">Help</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><a id="NavigationMenu_SkipLink"></a>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Both "header" and "page" classes have a width of "100%".

It was developed in asp.net using C#, and no Mobile.Master page was created as I don't really want to program an app.  I just want it to look normal on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change body width by CSS in different way and it works. Use Media Queries in your CSS as I write below:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) /* Desktop */ {
  body {
    your code here
  }
}

@media screen  and (max-width: 979px) /* Tablet */ {
  body {
   your code here
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) /* Mobile */ {
  body {
    your code here
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using tables is definitely not the way to go anymore. I would imagine that’s why you’re running into problems displaying on mobile screens. You should be using CSS Media Queries for responsive design.